# filter_var('.cgac...d@v1gac.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL); returns false for email including ... char

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I used php fileter_var function to validate email.

sample code:

```
$email_address = ".cgac...d@v1gac.com";
var_dump(filter_var($email_address, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));
```

this gives me result **false**;

The above sample email is just a sample email address and like email are actually valid emails.
Please reply me. I want to use the same filter_var function for validation.

And many php mailer library like **PHPMailer** also use internally same function for email validation.

Comment: That address is invalid. PHPMailer has several email validators to choose from, but this one is not the default.

Answer (score 1):

This e-mail address is invalid, valid e-mail address can't begins/ends with a dot `.`.

Comment: hi @panther thanks for reply please check email 'mahesh.@example12.com' for me this is email also returns false

Comment: @maheshkajale: Is a dot valid for the last one character in the "username"? Not sure, it seems that this is invalid too. Yes, it's invalid, see RFC5322, valid regex eg. here http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html